# decode base64 encode string with salt

Tags: php

I am using this piece of code to encrypt my password:-

```
 public function hashSSHA($password) {
     $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}
```

Now I realize that, I need  reverse process of it. So I tried with this

```
base64_decode(sha1(str_replace($password, $salt), true) . $salt);
```

and this

```
base64_decode(str_replace(sha1(str_replace($password, $salt), true) , $salt));
```

to get my decrypted password, But none of working.

Comment: Just, don't. Reinventing password hashing is dangerous and pointless. Use [PHP's Password API](http://www.php.net/password).

Comment: you're not "encrypting", you're hashing. there's a major difference between the two: crypting is reversable, hashing isn't.

Comment: In the future, take a look at [this answer about storing passwords in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/401684/1122242).

Answer (score 1):

Don't store encrypted passwords, store hashes. Just asking for trouble. [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) have a decent tutorial on this.

Edit after comments:
for forgot your password forms, you should only need to request their email. Send them an email with a link which includes some random value in the `get` which you also store in the database table. Confirm the values match, and let them change their password. Afterwards, change the value in the database to invalidate the link you sent them.

Comment: OP is using hashes, not encryption. Also, this isn't really an answer, but the link is useful, maybe add it to the comments instead.

Comment: I would have left a comment, just it requires 50 reputation for some reason.

Comment: When the question is "how do I shoot myself in the foot", a valid answer is "don't shoot yourself in the foot"

Comment: I am storing these "salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted, So i have these details to retrieve back my encrypted password.

Comment: No, you don't, because you're using SHA1 to hash the password, which is lossy. But there's no legitimate reason to ever be able to get the raw password back out of your database.

Comment: Actually this is old working code and many users info is saved like this, So i cant change algo now. Now i have only one option how i can retrieve my password back.

Comment: @moveaway00 Not without an explanation. You having a problem breathing doesn't make somebody replying "stop breathing then" an answer to your problem.

Comment: You *can't* retrieve the password. Cryptography at work. If this is a "forgot your password" type form, let the user change their password instead.

Comment: Ya this for forgot password. but how I validate users? thats why i want to decrypt their old password and send that to their registered email id.

Comment: Is this good if i create a random string and convert that again using this algo and save encrypted those data to DB and send that string to mail as password?

Comment: Not really. You shouldn't email plain text passwords. Emails aren't private. A post to your website should be though.

Comment: Actually this is for mobile app, And now we dont have free message service by which we can send user password on their mobile, So i am trying to use this approach.